# iOS App getting crashed after using camera and locking the screen for iphone with iOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, crash, lockscreen

I am developing an app for iOS which has a feature of taking photos through native camera app. I and my co-worker, we both are working on same application. He has XCODE 6 installed in his MAC, whereas, i am using  XCODE 9.

My concern is, whenever i install the app in IPHONE 5s(iOS 11), and use the camera function through my app, it works fine, even after i lock the screen and then come back, the app is still on the same page. But, when i run the app through his MAC(XCODE 6), the app gets crashed after using camera and locking the screen.

And this is happening after updating my IPHONE to iOS 11

Here i am posting some code about the camera functionality which i am using in my app.

code on camera button click :-

```
UIImagePickerController *cameraPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cameraPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    cameraPicker.delegate =self;
    [self presentViewController:cameraPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Its the same code we both use for taking images.

Can anyone please tell me why is this happening, because for uploading an app and making it live to app store, i am using his MAC(XCODE 6).

Comment: can u tell me the error after getting crash

Comment: @ios developer -  actually i am not able to generate the error as i install the app through xcode 9 and it doesnt crash, whereas my friend is not able to connect iphone to his system as he is using xcode 6. So he uploads the app to testflight and then we test after downloading, and that is where it crashes.

Comment: can you please help me out on this @ios developer

Comment: did u add this line in info.list  privacy - Camera Usage Description.may be this is sensitive data issue

Comment: yes i have this line 'Privacy - Camera Usage Description' in my info.plist file  @ios developer

Comment: Can anyone please help me out, what wrong am i doing or what should be done to prevent the app crash on lock screen, after taking an image from camera ?? (for xcode 6)

Answer (score 0):

Are you saving images to your device via app? if yes then include this permission in your info.plist "Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description".

If you try to save image without using this permission in xcode 9 or ios 11.0 , app crashes

Comment: ok. but my issue is that when i upload my app through xcode 6 and test it on device (ios 11) it crashes after clicking an image and locking the screen after it. when i come back, the app is terminated. @Muhammad Umer Farooq

Comment: it does not crashes when i run the app through xcode 9 on my device. The problem occurs when i use xcode 6.

Comment: debug the app through xcode 6 and post the exception detail in output window of xcode 6..may be then i can help you!

Comment: my problem is that i cannot connect my device to xcode 6 as my phone is having ios11 version, and xcode 6 does not support ios11. Also i cannot test it on simulator as for testing the camera you need a device. Can you suggest me some alternative for this?

Comment: Well, in that case i would suggest use only xcode 9 to release your app because xcode 6 has no support for ios 11 but still if u insist open your project in xcode 6 , click on "window" in top bar menu and choose organizer there you can check crash logs for your uploaded version